# "Properly" looping through (my)SQL response

Tags: php, mysql, associative-array

I have a class that does the MySQL stuff for me. 
I have 1 to n rows in a MySQL Table and want to query specific results.

To query a table, I can now use

```
$db->select('tablename', '*');
$res = $db->Result()
```

to get the results as an associative array.

Now if I want to loop through, I have to check if there is one or more results and then either display that one result or loop through the results.

This bloats up my code and I would like to find a way to combine both results.

At the moment, I am doing this stuff like so:

```
if(is_array($res[0]){
    //we have more than one result
    foreach($res as $something)
    {
        //do stuff here
    }
}
else
{
    //do the same stuff as above here but now with other variables since $something is only filled in the foreach loop
}
```

Now as said, I would love to combine those two and have only one piece of code to display the results (or work further with them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the input data structure into the format the loop expects, then iterate through it in the loop:

```
if(!is_array($res[0]){
    $res[0] = [$res[0]];
}

foreach($res as $something)
{
    //do stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to switch to some wide deveoped classes like PDO (http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or simply add a check in your `Result` method that returns an empty array in cases there are no results

```
function Result() {
    // stuff to fetch and fill $arr;
    return (is_array($arr[0])) $arr : array();
}
```

Comment: Would be possible, but that would require some time to adapt since the project is a few years old now. Will keep that in mind tough.